# Twitter & Blog links missing for Stack Overflow under SE 'All Sites' listing

Tags: discussion, blog, twitter

The links to Stack Overflow's 'Twitter' and 'Blog' accounts are missing under the Stack Exchange '[All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic)' listing. If you look at the 'Super User' or 'Server Fault' (and few others), they do link to 'Twitter' and/or 'Blog', if available. For example:

> [image]

I am aware of the fact that Stack Overflow blog i.e. [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/) is the same as (or combined with the SE blog) [blog.stackexchange.com](https://blog.stackexchange.com/) but *not sure* if that's the reason for *not* displaying the SO 'Blog' link.

Also, Stack Overflow does have it's own dedicated Twitter a/c: https://twitter.com/stackoverflow. I am curious to know why SO's 'Twitter' link is not displayed as well.

As per the Normal Human's comment:

> Stack Overflow does have a Twitter account now, so the question of why
> it isn't linked makes perfect sense. The list does not say that the
> account has to be a bot...

Can anyone please explain or point me to any documented evidence on the same.

Comment: There is no link because Stack Overflow simply does not have tweet bot, as explained in the dupe. (and the blog is a different issue, you can edit this question to focus only on the blog part and not twitter and I'll reopen)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The answer to that question is "No -- we can't obtain  stackoverflow..." which is no longer the case. Stack Overflow does have a Twitter account now, so the question of why it isn't linked makes perfect sense. The list does not say that the account has to be a bot...