# Why is Stack Overflow's Twitter account and blog both not linked in the list view on the all sites page on SE?

Tags: discussion, support, twitter

When going to the [sites section on SE in list view](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#users), you can see that many networks have their Twitter linked and Server Fault even has its blog linked.

However, both the [Twitter of SO](https://twitter.com/StackOverflow) and the [Blog of SO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) are not linked.

Is that a decision because they aren't posting questions or is that an oversight?

Comment: Dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/264212/282094 related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259316/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101340/282094 - It's not exactly a "blog" **about** Stack Overflow (.com) (and it's Q&As, maintained by the Moderators); it's the company's blog, and the subject content varies. --- The other site's Twitter has a preset feed, and the blog is from the Mods. --- Different mode of operation.